Separate excel columns with different lengths into multiple rows using Python
I am attempting to use python to loop through rows in an excel spreadsheet and separate data in a row into multiple rows if the column in question has multiple newlines or carriage returns.
In the example data set below, I would be using Col 3 to determine if a row needed to be expanded. The "current data set" shown is one row in excel where Col 3 - 8 have multiple lines within the cell. This would just be one row of multiple on my spreadsheet that would need expanded, and some may not have multiple newlines or carriage returns that would require a split. Col 1 and Col 2 will always be one line and will need to be added into the new rows. There is a potential for blank spots in the data that will just be empty newline-carriage returns that need to be accounted for in the goal data set. Col 3 - 8 will have the same amount of lines and the lines will represent the new rows.
I have tried to use pandas explode function but I am left with an absurd amount of copies of some of the rows. On one attempt, turning approximately 50 rows into 1,500 rows.
Current data set                            
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5   Col 6   Col 7   Col 8
Num 1   Num 2   "Num 3  "Text 1 "Num 7  "Text 5 "Num 11 "Text 9
                 Num 4   Text 2  Num 8   Text 6          Text 10
                 Num 5   Text 3  Num 9   Text 7  Num 12
                 Num 6"  Text 4" Num 10" Text 8" Num 13" Text 11"
        
                                            
                            
Goal data set                           
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5   Col 6   Col 7   Col 8
Num 1   Num 2   Num 3   Text 1  Num 7   Text 5  Num 11  Text 9
Num 1   Num 2   Num 4   Text 2  Num 8   Text 6          Text 10
Num 1   Num 2   Num 5   Text 3  Num 9   Text 7  Num 12  
Num 1   Num 2   Num 6   Text 4  Num 10  Text 8  Num 13  Text 11

data = pd.read_excel(f'Output\\spreadSheet.xlsx')
columns = data.columns.tolist()
for column in columns:
    if column == "Col 3":
        continue

    for idx, status in enumerate(data[column]):
        try:
            if '\n' in status:
                    data[column] = data[column].str.split('\n \n')
                    data = data.explode(column)
        except:
            continue

data.to_excel(f'Output\\spreadSheet.xlsx')


The way you have presented the data sets does not show carriage returns or newlines.  Also your goal data set contains the same number of rows as your current data set, so it seems you do not actually want to add any rows, or to create additional lines.  I think you need to find a better way of explaining what you want.

Thank you Paul. I have adjusted the spacing on the data set and added the comment "The "current data set" shown is one row in excel where Col 3 - 8 have multiple lines within the cell." I am starting with 1 row in excel where there are multiple lines in col 3- 8, sometimes up to 12 lines within a single cell. The goal data set is attempting to show that the single row is broken into multiple rows to account for the multiple lines.

I have created simple example to reproduce:
df = pd.DataFrame( [[1, 2, 'A\n2\n1\n3\n7', 
                     'A\n9\n9\n9\n9', 
                     'A\n2\nV\n4\n1', 
                     'A\n2\n1\n\n7', 
                     'A\n3\n1\n3\n3', 
                     'A\n\n\nB\nB']], columns =[f'Col {i}' for i in range(1,9)])
df





Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4
Col 5
Col 6
Col 7
Col 8




0
1
2
A\n2\n1\n3\n7
A\n9\n9\n9\n9
A\n2\nV\n4\n1
A\n2\n1\n\n7
A\n3\n1\n3\n3
A\n\n\nB\nB



I think that it's easier to create second data frame than modify presented one. Namely,
df_rep = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(df['Col 3'][0].split('\n'))), #number of indexes defined by col3
columns =[f'Col {i}' for i in range(1,9)])
df_rep

    





Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4
Col 5
Col 6
Col 7
Col 8




0
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


1
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


2
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


3
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN


4
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN



Then you can use following code:
df_rep['Col 1'] = df.iat[0,0]
df_rep['Col 2'] = df.iat[0,1]
for i in range(3,9):
    df_rep['Col {}'.format(i)] = df['Col {}'.format(i)][0].split('\n')
df_rep





Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4
Col 5
Col 6
Col 7
Col 8




0
1
2
A
A
A
A
A
A


1
1
2
2
9
2
2
3



2
1
2
1
9
V
1
1



3
1
2
3
9
4

3
B


4
1
2
7
9
1
7
3
B



Update: multiple rows
For the multi-row data frame:
df = pd.DataFrame( [[1, 2, 'A\n2\n1\n3\n7', 
                     'A\n9\n9\n9\n9', 
                     'A\n2\nV\n4\n1', 
                     'A\n2\n1\n\n7', 
                     'A\n3\n1\n3\n3', 
                     'A\n\n\nB\nB'], [2, 3, 'B\n2\n1\n3\n7', 
                     'B\n9\n9\n9\n9', 
                     'B\n2\nV\n4\n1', 
                     'B\n2\n1\n\n7', 
                     'B\n3\n1\n3\n3', 
                     'B\n\n\nB\nB']], columns =[f'Col {i}' for i in range(1,9)])




Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4
Col 5
Col 6
Col 7
Col 8




0
1
2
A\n2\n1\n3\n7
A\n9\n9\n9\n9
A\n2\nV\n4\n1
A\n2\n1\n\n7
A\n3\n1\n3\n3


1
2
3
B\n2\n1\n3\n7
B\n9\n9\n9\n9
B\n2\nV\n4\n1
B\n2\n1\n\n7
B\n3\n1\n3\n3



We can use following code:
df_rep = pd.DataFrame(columns =[f'Col {i}' for i in range(1,9)])

for i, row in enumerate(df.index):
    single_rep = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(df['Col 3'][i].split('\n'))), columns =[f'Col {i}' for i in range(1,9)]) #number of indexes defined by col3
    single_rep['Col 1'] = df.iat[i,0]
    single_rep['Col 2'] = df.iat[i,1]
    for j in range(3,9):
        single_rep['Col {}'.format(j)] = df['Col {}'.format(j)][i].split('\n')
    df_rep = pd.concat([df_rep, single_rep])
df_rep.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_rep stores all information about the loop, whereas single_rep is created independently for each row. It's overwritten inside the loop as well as df_rep by adding new rows. As output, we have:



Col 1
Col 2
Col 3
Col 4
Col 5
Col 6
Col 7
Col 8




0
1
2
A
A
A
A
A


1
1
2
2
9
2
2
3


2
1
2
1
9
V
1
1


3
1
2
3
9
4

3


4
1
2
7
9
1
7
3


5
2
3
B
B
B
B
B


6
2
3
2
9
2
2
3


7
2
3
1
9
V
1
1


8
2
3
3
9
4

3


9
2
3
7
9
1
7
3




Thank you! That is good advice on creating a second data frame. How would I use this to loop through all rows in a spreadsheet, determine what rows need to be split, and execute the script you wrote?

I've edited the answer to include a multirow situation.

I am running into a couple issues with this scenario and script that maybe you could help me out with.. 1) If a row is empty from Col 3 to the end, then it breaks. I am trying to use "df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = ['Col 3'])" to remove the row but it isn't working. 2) If Col 3 has more values then Col 4, then it breaks based on the length comparison. I Would like to just apply Col 4 to all instances of Col 3 if the lengths dont match but not sure how to add that into the script.
